# Unwrapping optionals in Apple's game code project template

Tags: swift, option-type, forced-unwrapping

In the small sample of Apple's code which is created when you make a new game project in Xcode, the GameScene has several functions which use an unwrapping pattern I've not come across, & I fail to see the point of it -

```
if let n = self.spinnyNode?.copy() as! SKShapeNode? { ...code... }
```

Two questions - (1) is this dangerous, & (2) why not use the more common pattern -

```
if let n = self.spinnyNode?.copy() as? SKShapeNode { ...code... }
```

I can find nothing relating to this on SO or Google...

Comment: @Anish웃 that does not answer the question: both examples the OP provided are downcasting. He is asking about the differences between them and the code in Apple's sample took the approach it did.

Comment: that was not the answer..just a link he could refer for study

Comment: Yup - I think I know about downcasting... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets break down the original line of code:

```
if let n = self.spinnyNode?.copy() as! SKShapeNode? { ...code... }
```

1. `self.spinnyNode` is declared as an `SKShapeNode?`. In other words, it's an optional `SKShapeNode`.
2. `SKShapeNode` inherits from `NSObject` which provides the `copy` method. The `copy` method is declared to return `Any`.
3. `self.spinnyNode?.copy()` will return an `Any?` with a value of `nil` if `self.spinnyNode` is `nil` or it will return a non-nil `Any?` if it's not.

So the compiler thinks that `self.spinnyNode?.copy()` will return an `Any?`. But we know it will really return a `SKShapeNode?`. Since we know what it will really be we can safely use `as!`. And since we know it will return a `SKShapeNode?`, we use `as! SKShapeNode?`.

At this point we could have:

```
let n = self.spinnyNode?.copy() as! SKShapeNode?
```

where `n` will be a `SKShapeNode?`.

Since we now want to safely unwrap the result, we add the `if` in front of the `let`:

```
if let n = self.spinnyNode?.copy() as! SKShapeNode? { ...code... }
```

and inside the block we know that `n` is a non-nil `SKShapeNode`.

With all of that, let's answer your questions:

1. Is this dangerous? No, not in this case since we know for sure that `self.spinnyNode?.copy()` will always result in a `SKShapeNode?` we can safely use `as!` to cast it to `SKShapeNode?`.
2. Why not use the more common `as? SKShapeNode` pattern? We could but that pattern is used when you don't know for sure that the result is actually a `SKShapeNode`.

Comment: Thanks - that clears it up nicely, though I do doubt that I would ever use that pattern myself